# Authorized vs unauthorized main view

Tags: angular

when my app is starting I check cookies and if user is authorized I want to show him MainComponent. If user is unauthorized LoginComponent needs to be shown.

Where this logic should be? In app.module.ts or in app.component.ts? How do I control which component will be shown? The logic "show MainComponent and then if user is unauthorized redirect to LoginComponent" isn't good, user wants to see proper component from start. How do I do that if root route is hardcoded in RouterModule?

Thanks.
P.S. Yes, I'm completely newbie in Angular 2 :)

Comment: you need to include some code form your attempt

Comment: There is no code, I need help with basic stretegy to make my attempt. I just have project with 3 components and routing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you need a `Guard` to add to your `Route`.

You need to setup a `Service` that will store the authenticated status of your user (that is set when you login for example),

and then add a `guard` on your route which will check your `service's boolean state`, and allow the route to be activated or not. If the guard returns `true`, the user can access the route, if not you need to redirect him to your `login` and return false.

---

Let's make that quite easily :

Setup the **auth.service.ts** :

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  public isAuthenticated: boolean = false;

  constructor(
     // Your DI needs
  ) { }

  // Sets the authenticated state
  setLoggedInState(): void {
    this.isAuthenticated = tokenNotExpired(); // I'm using angular2-jwt for token management
  }
}
```

Do not forget to add the provider for your service in your `ngModule()`

```
providers: [
  AuthService
]
```

Now, you are able to call your service from your component and set the authenticated state by calling your service using Dependency Injection :

```
onSubmit() {
  // I set my authenticated state from the service itself after I got the Token
  this.authService.getToken(this.currentUser.email,   this.currentUser.password)
    .subscribe((token) => {
      this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);  // Route that should be accessed upon login
    });
}
```

---

And now add a guard to your route

setup **auth.guard.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {
  }

  /**
   *  Protects the routes to reach with authentication
   */
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): any {
    if (this.authService.isAuthenticated) {
      return true;
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Update your `routes` with the guard:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
];
```

Do not forget to add the guard to the providers of your `appModule` (And be careful to provide it once as you need only a single instance of your guard).

```
providers: [
    AuthGuard
]
```

NB : Since you have a really tiny app yet, you will probably have both the AuthGuard and your service in the same `providers` array. Also, you don't need to setup a shared service for a guard.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I've got the idea.

Comment: No problem, glad I helped.

Comment: If you have any issue, do not hesitate to ask, and if that helped you, I would be thankful if you could mark as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Roman, Angular 2 provides you the CanAtivate method, which can be configured with your routes list to say if the user can access or not a particular route.

Basically, you need to configure your routes like this

```
import { AuthGuard } from './shared/auth-guard.service';
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'settings', [...other configurations...], canActivate: [AuthGuard] }
   ...other routes...
  ]
```

So whenever you try to visit the /settings page of your app, Angular will ask to AuthGuard if you can do it or not.

Here is my full implementation of AuthGuard (you might need to make some changes):

```
// Angular
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, NavigationExtras } from '@angular/router';

// Application
import { Session } from './index';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private session: Session, private router: Router) { }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        if (this.session.hasValidAuthToken()) // check if the user can acess the route or not
            return true; // let the user to access the route

        let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
            preserveQueryParams: false,
            queryParams: { url: state.url }
        };

        //if not, redirect to the login route
        this.router.navigate(['/login'], navigationExtras);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: `RouterModule.forRoot([
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'page1', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'page1', component: Page1Component, canActivate: [AppGuard] },
    { path: 'page2', component: Page2Component },
    { path: 'page3', component: Page3Component },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: 'page1' }
])`

Here are my routes. I've added guard to my default page and as guard returns false, I got blank screen. So how to show login screen instead?

Comment: When AuthGuard (in your case AppGuard) returns false the target route won't be loaded. Instead, your AppGuard must redirect the navigation to your login.component.
Do you already have a loging.component?

Comment: Now I see. Thanks a lot!